# How to find sentences from txt file in. c++?

Tags: c++, string

My problem is to read txt file and print 1 sentence per line but I am not sure how I can do this, I have the following code for finding of the sentence ending tho:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream infile("test.txt",ios::in);
    string current;
    int count=0;
    while(getline(infile, current))
    {
        for(int i=0;i<current.size();i++)
            if(current[i]=='.' || current[i]=='?' || current[i]=='!')
                count++;
    }
    cout<<"Total Sentences: "<<count<<"\n";

  return 0;
}
```

So how can I print them one by line? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Your code currently reads the sentence character by character and throws away the result. Why not use a `std::string sentence` and append non-sentence-ending characters to it as you see them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the sentence start and then once you have the sentence end create a substring. This substring will be between in the range [sentence_start, i].

```cpp
int sentence_start = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < current.size(); i++) {
    // if sentence end
    if (current[i] == '.' || current[i] == '?' || current[i] == '!') {
        // get sentence substring
        string sentence = current.substr(sentence_start, (i + 1) - sentence_start);
        ...
```

Once you have this sentence substring, you can print it with a newline.

```cpp
// output sentence
cout << sentence << endl;
```

Finally, you should update the sentence start.

```cpp
// update sentence start
sentence_start = i + 1;
```

Increase the sentence start if it is on a whitespace character.

```cpp
// if sentence start and whitespace
if (i == sentence_start && isspace(current[i])) {
    // increase sentence start
    sentence_start++;
}
```

---

Your while loop becomes:

```cpp
while (getline(infile, current)) {
    int sentence_start = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < current.size(); i++) {
        // if sentence end
        if (current[i] == '.' || current[i] == '?' || current[i] == '!') {
            // get sentence substring
            string sentence = current.substr(sentence_start, (i + 1) - sentence_start);
            // output sentence
            cout << sentence << endl;
            // update sentence start
            sentence_start = i + 1;
            // increase count
            count++;
        }
        // if sentence start and whitespace
        if (i == sentence_start && isspace(current[i])) {
            // increase sentence start
            sentence_start++;
        }
    }
}
```

---

The result of the file

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

is

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Total Sentences: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Parsing sentences straight from a file adds some difficulty to the problem. You are far better off reading the entire file into memory tokenizing it to a vector. This allows you to format the data much much easier before processing it.

A generic tokenizer

```
std::string A = P; //P is the Filepath
std::ifstream fsinput;
fsinput.open(A);

std::string Line;
if(fsinput.is_open())
{
while(std::getline(fsinput, Line))
{
if(Line.size() == 0)
    tokens.push_back("");
    //preserves blank lines

 std::size_t prev = 0, pos;
 while((pos = Line.find_first_of(" ", prev)) != std::string::npos)                     
// The " " is where you can put delimeters
 {
   if(pos >prev)
   {
        tokens.push_back(Line.substr(prev,   `           pos-prev));    
   }
prev = pos+1;
}

if(prev < Line.length())
     tokens.push_back(Line.substr(prev, std::string::npos));
}
fsinpit.close();
```

This will generate a vector of space seperated tokens with blank lines preserved. You can then process the vector like this....

```
std::string sentence = "";
for(int i =0; i<tokens.size(); i++)
{
     if (tokens[i] != "")
     {
         if(sentence == "")
         {
             sentence= tokens[i];
         }
         else
         {
            sentence = sentence + " " + tokens[i];
         }//else
     }//if
     else
    {
      token1.push_back(sentence);//complete line
      token1.push_back("");//preserving blank line
      sentence ="";
    }//else
}//for
```

This will reassemble the individual tokens into single token sentences and single token paragraphs based on the formatting lines. There might be some sentence fragments in files converted down to txt do to poor formatting. Easy enough however once you see them to write a cleanup function and give the vector a second pass to concatenate them where they belong.

At this point Lily's answer will be able to extract all of the sentences from the vector. Just change the "while" to a "for" loop to walk the vector and assign the current token to "current".